# Javascript ES6, how to add value to array inside a newly copied object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in ES6 there is a new way to copy objects so you can have a nice way to handle inmutable states:

```
let oldObj = { foo: 1}; // { foo: 1 }

let newObj = { ...oldObj, bar: 2 }; // { foo: 1, bar: 2}
```

However what I want to achieve is:

```
let oldObj = { foo: [1] }; // { foo: [1] }

let newObj = ??? // { foo: [1, 2] }
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: `{ ...oldObj, foo: [...oldObj.foo, 2] }` --- no easy way here. PS: the syntax you're referring to is not "ES6" and is not even standardised yet.

Comment: ah, is it babel then?

Comment: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread --- it is a stage-2 proposal

Comment: good to know, thank you for the quick reply

Comment: just to clarify, spread operator is part of ES6 for Arrays, just not for Objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Zerkms answer a bit better because it is more general, if your object contains more keys other than the array:

```
{ ...oldObj, foo: [...oldObj.foo, 2] }
```

Credit to @Zerkms.

Answer (score 4):

```
let newObj = { foo: [...oldObj.foo, 2] }
```

You could also have a look at Immutable js - http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic value [...oldObj.foo, bar]

```js
let oldObj = { foo: [1] }; // { foo: [1] }
let newObj = { ...oldObj, foo: [1, 2] } // { foo: [1, 2] }
console.log(newObj)

let oldObj2 = { foo: [1] }; // { foo: [1] }
let bar = 2
let newObj2 = { foo:  [...oldObj.foo, bar] } // { foo: [1, 2] }
console.log(newObj2)
```